# r - reorder certain rows if condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a dataframe in which some rows need to be reordered. For example take:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 id = c("s","s","s","i","s","s","i","s","s","s"),
                 var1 = c(3,5,6,4,-7,2,1,-1,3,-6),
                 var2 = c(2,6,-7,5,-9,7,3,2,4,-9))
```

In this dataframe the rows in which `id == "i"` need to be reordered. Reordering should be done by only comparing the values in other rows within a group (in this case column `name` can be used to `group_by`). The condition for the reordering is the following, for ex. if the current row to check is the row in which `id == "i"` then check if:

```
var1 < lead(var1) & var1 > lag(var1) & var2 < lead(var2) & var2 > lag(var2)
```

If FALSE then it means that this row should be moved until this condition is TRUE.

After the reordering the final product should be:

```
df_output <- data.frame(name = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                        id = c("s","i","s","s","s","s","s","i","s","s"),
                        var1 = c(3,4,5,6,-7,2,-1,1,3,-6),
                        var2 = c(2,5,6,-7,-9,7,2,3,4,-9))
```

Note that in the first group the row in which `id == "i"` has moved from the 4th position to the 2th position, while in the second group it has moved from the 2th to the 3th position.

Can this be done, with `tidyverse` if possible (if not with any that works) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As IMO it is not possible/neseccary to check two variables for the position I will use onyl `var1`.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(gr1=1:n()) %>% 
  mutate(gr2=first(which(var1 < var1[id =="i"]))) %>% 
  mutate(gr3= ifelse(id=="i", gr2+0.1, gr1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(name, gr3) %>% 
  select(-starts_with("gr"))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
    name id     var1  var2
   <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1 s         3     2
 2     1 i         4     5
 3     1 s         5     6
 4     1 s         6    -7
 5     1 s        -7    -9
 6     2 s         2     7
 7     2 s        -1     2
 8     2 i         1     3
 9     2 s         3     4
10     2 s        -6    -9
```

The idea is to find per `name` group the first `var1` value smaller than the "`i`" value using `first`. Finally updating the arranging vector `gr` with `ifelse` and arranging.

Comment: by IMO you refer to?

Comment: both variables are needed to see if the condition is met. The var1 and var2 are actually longitude and latitude. They are both crucial for the algorithm.

Comment: @adl Then revise your question and include some data which illustrates why you need both.

Comment: I believe the condition is well explained in the question. I cannot disclose why I need this specific condition, but it is related to finding if a point defined with longitude(var1) and latitude(var2) is within certain limits.

Comment: This " finding if a point defined with longitude(var1) and latitude(var2) is within certain limits." is a completely other question as above. But as you can't provide adequate sample data, I'm out now. My code is working for data like you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, like that? But I didn't undestand what you did with 'i' rows that have no place to go to or more than one place. Things would be much more simpler if 's' rows were ordered.

```
dfs <- filter(df, id=="s")
dfi <- filter(df, id=="i")

dfs$x <- (!is.na(lead(dfs$name)) & dfs$name==lead(dfs$name) & dfs$var1<lead(dfs$var1) & dfs$var2<lead(dfs$var2)) |
         (!is.na(lag(dfs$name))  & dfs$name==lag(dfs$name)  & dfs$var1>lag(dfs$var1)  & dfs$var2>lag(dfs$var2) )
dfs$y <- row.names(dfs)
dfs1 <- filter(dfs,x) %>% select(-x)
dfs0 <- filter(dfs,!x) %>% select(-x)
dfi$y <- ""
df2 <- arrange(rbind(dfs1,dfi),name,var1,var2)
df2$y <- ifelse(df2$y=="",paste0(lag(df2$y),",",row.names(df2)),df2$y)
df_output <- arrange(rbind(df2,dfs0),y) %>% select(-y)
```